# Display drowDown with names country by original language

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have application building bt React. I have to display the drop-down list with names country by original language. Also, I should display regions and countries, also each on the original language.

Could you help me with this? Maybe exist packages for this. But I can't found. Or I should have a large JSON with hardcoву names country... Maybe whoms know where I can found cooked Json with all names countries, regions... ?

Comment: As a side remark, I live in Belgium and wonder which of our 3 national languages are you going to choose?

Answer (score 2):

I created this JSON for you from this source: https://www.worldatlas.com/articles/names-of-countries-in-their-own-languages.html

SO cut the file because of the character limit, so I uploaded it here:
https://github.com/tomeralmog/zipcode-kml/blob/master/countries.json

```
[{
    countryName: 'Afghanistan',
    language: 'Dari, Pashto',
    nativeCountryName: 'افغانستانAfghanestan',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Albania',
    language: 'Albanian',
    nativeCountryName: 'Shqipëria',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Algeria',
    language: 'Arabic, Berber',
    nativeCountryName: 'Dzayer',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Andorra',
    language: 'Catalan',
    nativeCountryName: 'Andorra',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Angola',
    language: 'Kongo, Portuguese',
    nativeCountryName: 'Angola',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Antigua and Barbuda',
    language: 'English',
    nativeCountryName: 'Antigua and Barbuda',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Argentina',
    language: 'Spanish',
    nativeCountryName: 'Argentina',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Armenia',
    language: 'Armenian',
    nativeCountryName: 'Hayastán',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Australia',
    language: 'English',
    nativeCountryName: 'Australia',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Austria',
    language: 'German',
    nativeCountryName: 'Österreich',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Azerbaijan',
    language: 'Azerbaijani',
    nativeCountryName: 'Azərbaycan',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'The Bahamas',
    language: 'English',
    nativeCountryName: 'The Bahamas',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Bahrain',
    language: 'Arabic, Berber',
    nativeCountryName: 'البحرينAl-Bahrayn',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Bangladesh',
    language: 'Bengali',
    nativeCountryName: 'Bangladesh বাংলাদেশ',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Barbados',
    language: 'English',
    nativeCountryName: 'Barbados',
  },
  {
    countryName: 'Belarus',
    language: 'Belarusian',
    nativeCountryName: 'Bielaruś, Беларусь',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Belgium',
          language: 'Dutch, French, German',
          nativeCountryName: 'België, Belgique, Belgien',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Belize',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Belize',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Benin',
          language: 'French',
          nativeCountryName: 'Bénin',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Bhutan',
          language: 'Dzongkha',
          nativeCountryName: 'Druk Yul, འབྲུག་ཡུལ',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Bolivia',
          language: 'Aymara, Guaraní, Quechua, Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Wuliwya, Volívia, Buliwya, Bolivia',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina',
          language: 'Bosnian, Serbian, Croatian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Bosnia I Hercegovína, Босна и Херцеговина',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Botswana',
          language: 'English, Tswana',
          nativeCountryName: 'Botswana',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Brazil',
          language: 'Portuguese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Brasil',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Brunei',
          language: 'Malay',
          nativeCountryName: 'Brunei بروني',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Bulgaria',
          language: 'Bulgarian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Bulgariya, България',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Burkina Faso',
          language: 'French',
          nativeCountryName: 'Burkina Faso',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Burundi',
          language: 'French, Kirundi',
          nativeCountryName: 'Burundi, Uburundi',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Cambodia',
          language: 'Khmer',
          nativeCountryName: 'Kampuchea កម្ពុជា',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Cameroon',
          language: 'English, French',
          nativeCountryName: 'Cameroon, Cameroun',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Canada',
          language: 'English, French',
          nativeCountryName: 'Canada',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Cape Verde',
          language: 'Portuguese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Cabo Verde',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Central African Republic',
          language: 'French, sango',
          nativeCountryName: 'République Centrafricaine, Ködörösêse tî Bêafrîka',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Chad',
          language: 'Arabic, French',
          nativeCountryName: 'Tchad, تشاد',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Chile',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Chile',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'China',
          language: 'Mandarin Chinese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Zhōngguó 中国',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Colombia',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Colombia',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Comoros',
          language: 'Arabic, French, Shikomor',
          nativeCountryName: 'جزر القمر Comores Koromi',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Republic of the Congo',
          language: 'French, Lingala',
          nativeCountryName: 'République du Congo, Republíki ya Kongó',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Democratic Republic of the Congo',
          language: 'French, Lingala, Swahili',
          nativeCountryName:
            'République démocratique du Congo, Republíki ya Kongó, Demokratíki Jamhuri ya Kidemokrasia ya Kongo',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Costa Rica',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Costa Rica',
        },
        {
          countryName: "Côte d'Ivoire",
          language: 'French',
          nativeCountryName: "Côte d'Ivoire",
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Croatia',
          language: 'Croatian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Hrvatska',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Cuba',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Cuba',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Cyprus',
          language: 'Greek, Turkish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Κύπρος Kıbrıs',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Czechia',
          language: 'Czech',
          nativeCountryName: 'Česko',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Denmark',
          language: 'Danish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Danmark',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Djibuti',
          language: 'Arabic, French',
          nativeCountryName: 'جيبوتي Djibouti',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Dominica Republic',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'República Dominicana',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'East Timor',
          language: 'Portuguese, Tetum',
          nativeCountryName: "Timor-Lester, Timor Lorosa'e",
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Ecuador',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Ecuador',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Egypt',
          language: 'Arabic',
          nativeCountryName: 'مصرMisr',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'El Salvador',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'El Salvador',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Equatorial Guinea',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Guinea Ecuatorial',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Eritrea',
          language: 'Arabic, Tigrinya',
          nativeCountryName: 'Iritriya إرتريا Ertra',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Estonia',
          language: 'Estonian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Eesti',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Eswatini',
          language: 'English, Swazi',
          nativeCountryName: 'Eswatini, eSwatini',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Ethiopia',
          language: 'Amharic',
          nativeCountryName: "Ityop'ia ኢትዮጵያ",
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Fiji',
          language: 'English, Fijian, Fiji Hindi',
          nativeCountryName: 'Fiji, Viti, फ़िजी',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Finland',
          language: 'Finnish, Swedish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Suomi, Finland',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'France',
          language: 'French',
          nativeCountryName: 'France',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Gabon',
          language: 'French',
          nativeCountryName: 'République gabonaise',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'The Gambia',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'The Gambia',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Georgia',
          language: 'Georgian',
          nativeCountryName: "Sak'art'velo საქართველო",
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Germany',
          language: 'German',
          nativeCountryName: 'Deutschland',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Ghana',
          language: 'Akan, English, Ewe, Twi',
          nativeCountryName: 'Gaana, Ghana, Gana, Gana',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Greece',
          language: 'Greek',
          nativeCountryName: 'Hellas Ελλάς',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Grenada',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Grenada',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Guatemala',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Guatemala',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Guinea',
          language: 'French, Manika, Pular',
          nativeCountryName: 'Guinée, Gine, Gine',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Guyana',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Guyana',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Haiti',
          language: 'French, Haitian Creole',
          nativeCountryName: 'Haïti, Ayiti',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Honduras',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Honduras',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Hong Kong',
          language: 'English, Cantonese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Hong Kong, Heung Gong, 香港',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Hungary',
          language: 'Hungarian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Magyarország',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Iceland',
          language: 'Icelandic',
          nativeCountryName: 'Ísland',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'India',
          language:
            'Assamese, Bengali, English, Hindi, Kannada, Konkai, Malayalam, Marthi, Nepalese, Oriya, Punjabi, Sanskrit, Tamil, Telugu',
          nativeCountryName:
            'Bharôt ভাৰত, Bharôt ভারত, India, Bhārat ભારત, Bhārat भारत, Bhārata ಭಾರತ, Bhārat भारत, Bhāratam ഭാരതം, Bhārat भारत, Bhārat भारत, Bharôtô ଭାରତ, Bhārat ਭਾਰਤ, Bhāratam भारतम्, Bārata பாரதம், Bhāratadēsam భారత దేశం',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Indonesia',
          language: 'Bahasa Indonesia',
          nativeCountryName: 'Indonesia',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Iran',
          language: 'Persian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Īrān ایران',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Iraq',
          language: 'Arabic, Kurdish',
          nativeCountryName: "Al-'Iraq العراق",
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Ireland',
          language: 'English, Irish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Ireland, Éire',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Israel',
          language: 'Arabic, Hebrew',
          nativeCountryName: "Israʼiyl إسرائيل, Yisra'el ישראל",
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Italy',
          language: 'Italian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Italia',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Jamaica',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Jamaica',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Japan',
          language: 'Japanese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Nippon 日本',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Jordan',
          language: 'Arabic',
          nativeCountryName: "Al-'Urdun الأردن",
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Kazakhstan',
          language: 'Kazakh, Russian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Qazaqstan Қазақстан, Kazakhstán Казахстан',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Kenya',
          language: 'English, Swahili',
          nativeCountryName: 'Kenya',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'North Korea',
          language: 'Korean',
          nativeCountryName: 'Chosŏn 조선 Bukchosŏn 북조선',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'South Korea',
          language: 'Korean',
          nativeCountryName: 'Hanguk 한국 Namhan 남한',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Kosovo',
          language: 'Albanian, Serbian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Kosova, Косово',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Kuwait',
          language: 'Arabic',
          nativeCountryName: 'Dawlat ul-Kuwayt دولة الكويت',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Kyrgyzstan',
          language: 'Kyrgyz, Russian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Kyrgyzstan Кыргызстан, Kirgizija Киргизия',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Laos',
          language: 'Lao',
          nativeCountryName: 'Lao ປະເທດລາວ',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Latvia',
          language: 'Latvia',
          nativeCountryName: 'Latvija',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Lebanon',
          language: 'Arabic, French',
          nativeCountryName: 'Lubnān لبنان, Liban',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Lesotho',
          language: 'English, Sesotho',
          nativeCountryName: 'Lesotho',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Libya',
          language: 'Berber, Arabic',
          nativeCountryName: 'Libya, Lībiyā ليبيا',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Liechtenstein',
          language: 'German',
          nativeCountryName: 'Liechtenstein',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Lithuania',
          language: 'Lithuanian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Lietuva',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Luxembourg',
          language: 'French, German, Luxembourgish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Luxembourg, Luxemburg, Lëtezebuerg',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Madagascar',
          language: 'French, Malagasy',
          nativeCountryName: 'Madagascar, Madagasikara',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Malawi',
          language: 'Chichewa, English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Malaŵi, Malawi',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Malaysia',
          language: 'Mandarin Chinese, Malay, Tamil',
          nativeCountryName: 'Mǎláixīyà 马来西亚, Malaysia, மலேசியா',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Maldives',
          language: 'Dhivehi',
          nativeCountryName: 'Dhivehi Raajje',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Mali',
          language: 'Bambara, French',
          nativeCountryName: 'Mali, Mali',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Malta',
          language: 'English, Maltese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Malta, Malta',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Marshall Islands',
          language: 'English, Marshallese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Marshall Islands, Aorōkin M̧ajeļ',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Mauritania',
          language: 'Arabic, Berer',
          nativeCountryName: 'Muritan / Agawec, Mūrītānyā موريتانيا',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Mauritius',
          language: 'English, French, Mauritian Creole',
          nativeCountryName: 'Mauritius, Maurice, Moris',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Mexico',
          language: 'Nahuatl, Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Mēxihco, México',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Federated States of Micronesia',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Federated States of Micronesia',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Moldova',
          language: 'Romanian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Moldova',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Monaco',
          language: 'French, Monégasque',
          nativeCountryName: 'Monaca, Múnegu',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Mongolia',
          language: 'Mongolia',
          nativeCountryName: 'Mongol Uls Монгол Улс',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Montenegro',
          language: 'Montenegrin',
          nativeCountryName: 'Crna Gora Црна Гора',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Morocco',
          language: 'Arabic, Berber',
          nativeCountryName: 'Al-maɣréb المغرب, Amerruk / Elmeɣrib',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Mozambique',
          language: 'Portuguese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Moçambique',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Myanmar',
          language: 'Burmese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Myanma မြန်မာ',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Namibia',
          language: 'Afrikaans, Engish, Damara, German, Herero',
          nativeCountryName: 'Namibia, Namibia, Namibia, Namibia, Namibia',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Nepal',
          language: 'Davanagari, Nepalese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Nepāl नेपाल',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'The Netherlands',
          language: 'Dutch, West Frisian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Nederland, Nederlân',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'New Zealand',
          language: 'English, Māori',
          nativeCountryName: 'New Zealand, Aotearoa',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Nicaragua',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Nicaragua',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Niger',
          language: 'French',
          nativeCountryName: 'Niger',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Nigeria',
          language: 'English, Hausa, Igbo, Yoruba',
          nativeCountryName: 'Nigeria, Nijeriya, Naigeria, Nàìjíríà',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'North Macedonia',
          language: 'Macedonian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Severna Makedonija Северна Македонија',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Norway',
          language: 'Norwegian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Norge',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Oman',
          language: 'Arabic',
          nativeCountryName: '‘Umān عُمان',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Pakistan',
          language: 'English, Urdu',
          nativeCountryName: 'Pākistān پاکستان',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Palau',
          language: 'English, Palauan',
          nativeCountryName: 'Palau, Belau',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Palestine',
          language: 'Arabic',
          nativeCountryName: 'Filasṭīn فلسطين',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Panama',
          language: 'Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Panamá',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Papua New Guinea',
          language: 'English, Hiri Motu, Tok Pisin',
          nativeCountryName: 'Papua New Guinea, Papua Niugini, Papua Giugini',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Paraguay',
          language: 'Guaraní, Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Paraguái, Paraguay',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Peru',
          language: 'Aymara, Spanish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Piruw, Perú',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Philippines',
          language: 'English, Filipino',
          nativeCountryName: 'Philippines, Pilipinas',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Poland',
          language: 'Polish',
          nativeCountryName: 'Polska',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Portugual',
          language: 'Portuguese',
          nativeCountryName: 'Portugal',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Qatar',
          language: 'Arabic',
          nativeCountryName: 'Qaṭar قطر',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Romania',
          language: 'Romanian',
          nativeCountryName: 'România',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Russia',
          language: 'Russian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Rossiâ Россия',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Rwanda',
          language: 'English, French, Kinyarwanda, Swahili',
          nativeCountryName: 'Rwanda',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Saint Kitts and Nevis',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Saint Lucia',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Saint Lucia',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Saint Vincent and the Grenadines',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Samoa',
          language: 'English, Samoan',
          nativeCountryName: 'Samoa, Sāmoa',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'San Marino',
          language: 'Italian',
          nativeCountryName: 'San Marino',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'São Tomé and Principe',
          language: 'Portuguese',
          nativeCountryName: 'São Tomé e Principe',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Saudi Arabia',
          language: 'Arabic',
          nativeCountryName: 'Al-‘Arabiyyah as Sa‘ūdiyyah المملكة العربية السعودية',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Senegal',
          language: 'French',
          nativeCountryName: 'Sénégal',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Serbia',
          language: 'Serbian',
          nativeCountryName: 'Srbija Србија',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Seychelles',
          language: 'English, French, Seychellois Creole',
          nativeCountryName: 'Seychelles, Seychelles, Sesel',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Sierra Leone',
          language: 'English',
          nativeCountryName: 'Sierra Leone',
        },
        {
          countryName: 'Singapore',
          language: 'English, Malay, Mandarin Chinese, Tamil',
          nativeCountryName: 'Singapore, Singapura, 新加坡, சிங்கப்பூர்',
        },
       
      ];
```

Comment: Yes, I can, but each country should display on  local language.
For example, if that Russia, she should display like  "Россия" If that China she should display like 中国.   And so for every country....

Comment: I created this json for you, but I had to cut some of the countries because of SO character limit...

Comment: But that does not resolve issues with display country regions and cities. 
Can I get a detailed list for regions of countries and cities somewhere?